# Add TextBox dynamically to webpage using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to add a textbox to a webpage in ASP.NET MVC using jQuery. I have a button which when clicked, I want a TB to be added to the end of a collection of Textboxes of a given class.
Here is my jQuery code for adding a textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#addTextBox").click(function () {

    var count = $('input:text .approvers').length;

    if (count <= 20) {

        var newTextBox = $(document.createElement('text'));

        newTextBox.appendTo('.approvers:last');
    }
});
```

});

Here is the button I have created in an MVC View

```
 <input type="button" value="+" id="addTextBox" class="roundButton" />
```

This however isn't working. Its defined in an external JS file. I have researched and made sure jQuery is added first before my own JS file. What have I missed out.

PS: I added a breakpoint at the start of the jQuery function and it gave me this warning when I debugged  **The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document** I am working on solving that but am not sure that may be the problem.

Comment: Show your view code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
var newTextBox = $(document.createElement('text'));

newTextBox.appendTo('.approvers:last');
```

to:

```
$('.approvers:last').append($("<input type='text' value='value' />"))
```

update:
Another error is `var count = $('input:text .approvers').length;`?
change it to : `var count = $('input[type='text'].approvers').length`;

Comment: I have tried that and its not working, am not sure if the click event even gets raised. Should I add a 'onclick' to the button and let it reference the jQuery method? And what is wrong with my original code?

Comment: I actually have changed the code for returning count to this 
  **var count = $('.approvers').length;** 
Since all I need is all textboxes of class 'approvers' However this still doesn't work.

Comment: okay then use jsfiddle to post your html , css and js. So that we can help.